# Как сохранить состояния действия js скрипта?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Я написал скрипт на js, который в свою очередь при нажатии на кнопку делает div блок видимым (изначально не видимый). Но при нажатии обновляется страница и блок сразу же исчезает. Каким образом я могу сделать его статическим. Пробовал сохранить по значениям куки, но видимо - эта реализация бред...
На js пишу всего 2 день. Сервер на c#.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Покажите код кнопки ImageButton1

Answer (score 0):

Извиняюсь, подсказали на другом портале. Проблема решается благодаря: `event.preventDefault();`